# safari 13.1 navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() return only audio devices

Tags: safari, webcam, navigator, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

Im facing with an issue on desktop Safari 13.1 version. If I open the console in the web inspector (with a regular macbook which has webcam and mic) and execute this command on any kind of website:

`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`

First time it will return in the Promise result with a videoinput and an audioinput.
Second time it will return only 2 audioinput. Videoinput is disappear.

Unfortunately I call this method several times while checking the available devices on my solution.

Any idea why does it happen and how could I get the accurate information about the devices even If I call it more than once?
[See the results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5uc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the same issue, also on my iPad running iOS 13.

It seems you need to request camera access first in order to see the correct device list.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
```

This will prompt you for access to the camera (you need to be on HTTPS or localhost).

Grant permission, then run this again and you should see the `videoinput` device(s) listed in the returned promise:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
```

I guess this makes sense as a privacy feature that a website cannot check if a camera exists without first asking your permission.